# Bypass random id in Firebase Realtime REST

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

If my data structure looks like this:

```
documents.json:
{
  "-NG8qzvgs46A5gojZbJO": {
    "-NG8r-2q1-47MWK35aT2": {
      "description": "My Description",
      "title": "My Title"
    },
    "author": "jim",
    "date": "05/11/2022"
  },
  "-NG8ta4xpHGZxA4JRUQZ": {
    "-NG8ta9e90ChdMQclirn": {
      "description": "My Description",
      "title": "My Title tom"
    },
    "author": "tom",
    "date": "04/11/2022"
  },
  "-NG8tjfP_TYJHZcjouY8": {
    "-NG8tjiryoxnWbb4wwQQ": {
      "description": "My Description ccc",
      "title": "My Title jim"
    },
    "author": "jim",
    "date": "05/11/2022"
  }
}
```

How to get all the entries where author="jim"?
This does not work:

```
https://testing-11f41-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/documents.json?orderBy="author"&equalTo="jim"
```

Is it possible using Firebase REST API?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not need to specify `$key`, but just `orderBy="myKey"`. If you can't get that to work, can you edit your question to include an actual URL and actual JSON showing the problem?

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I have updated the question. I was not able to filter by the term specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I access the URL you give, I get this response:

> {
> "error" : "Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "author", for path "/documents", to the rules"
> }

As this message says, you need to [add an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) to allow this query.

In your rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "documents": {
      ".indexOn": "author"
    }
  }
}
```